# Allow the search of content and/or users based on your preferences and quality?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, quality

Voting is a rough measure of quality * quantity or more specifically for questions/answers: quality * views/popularity.

This leads to *poor* search results if you are looking specifically for *hidden gems* in fields that are either too *niche* or the subject is relatively *advanced* and demands a high level of expertise to fathom.

Sometimes I come to the site with a desire to learn/teach new things (read and/or answer questions) that suit my preferences. I don't specifically have an issue I want to solve, I just wish to interact with the knowledge base that is relevant to my domain/hobbies/interests.

Currently, you can only search by tags - which are highly generic and lack some specificity. You can't discern between beginner/advanced/expert questions and can't look specifically for low popularity questions with a good score.

After you gain some reputation, the system should have enough data to predict which questions are of interest to you or alternatively, let you have the tools to search for them (so you can answer them). It should probably also take note of which users may have similar interests. This data could then be used to recommend questions/answers that are more valuable to a specific user.

Comment: What does this have to do with the reputation system? Nothing as far as I can see, you're asking for more intelligent filtering. What this does mean is that it's less likely I'll see something _new_ that I'll like. You've already boxed me into a corner.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but its important that when people ask "what does this number mean" that they get a decent answer and not "this incredibly complex formula generated it"

Comment: Finally; a lot of the "netflix reccomendation" stuff already happens on the question level on the home page (my homepage will show very different questions to yours). This clouds what I think you're trying to talk about; rep

Comment: @RichardTingle - Theoretically, If imaginary person X enjoys answering complex questions about C++ and person Y uses the fastest gun in the west routine to answer questions relating to homework assignments. Person Z downvotes questions about hw assignments and upvotes advanced questions about C++ than I suppose person Z would like to see person X as high reputation and person Y as low rep. People should be ranked based on who's viewing as well.
I think the question needs to be edited for clarification. Cutting down the clutter and focusing on the point.

Comment: Basically people like X should be measured against their kin and people like Y should also be measured likewise against similar folks and people who aren't interested in beginner questions and don't upvote them, possibly don't care how many questions like that Y has answered successfully.

Comment: I can see the argument in that, be careful not to "destroy the game" though. The rep system drives a lot of positive behaviour (like answering lots of questions with high quality answers) be careful not to remove that

Comment: I opened this issue for discussion to hear opinions so we could form a useful proposition for a feature. I don't think a specific proposition has crystallize in my mind but I feel it is worthy of discussion and could help users get a quick idea of other users and questions content. The general idea is that reputation is too narrow. It should not be a measure of how awesome A is but of how useful A is to B and similar folk.

Comment: It is important to note that none of us have a clear definition of what is objectively advance but we all have a good idea of what is advance in our opinion when we see it and that is why some intelligently collected crowd sourced information could help clue us in the right direction.

Comment: Questions are not "ranked one dimensionally".  Everybody that's logged-in gets a personalized view of the front page.  Based on previous interest in [tags] as well as the likes and dislikes they entered in their profile.  Use the Preferences tab to set your own.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite I've edited your question title to reflect the gist of what I think you're actually trying to ask.

Comment: @michaelb958 Thanks for helping to narrow down the issue. I edited the question to further focus on the interesting bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you're running into is this: **our voting system is not a ranking system.**

Netflix has a ranking system because it's a useful way to interact with the system and a core method of discovering content you're interested in. When you use Netflix, you can count on there being a list of stuff you might be interested in.

That isn't a useful way to interact with Stack Exchange, though. This is a place to find solutions to specific problems, not a TV network. Chances are if you're looking for something here, you have a problem that needs solving, and you're not going to visit a tag with several hundred questions and go page by page, no matter *how* it is ranked or sorted. You're going to use Google and a site-specific search until you find your question or give up. Search is your core method of discovering the content you're interested in here, not rankings.

Stack Exchange's voting comes in [as a rough measure of quality](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/). On answers, positive votes tell you the answer you're reading to your problem is *probably* pretty helpful. Negative votes tell you it isn't. On questions, they're a measure of quality again, but probably moreso a measure of community moderation.

Comment: This is a great answer *but* it disregards the fact that when you just wish to browse questions and answers out of interest and curiosity you can click "Questions" => "Votes" and get a sorted list of questions and answers. You can't however click "Questions" => "People like me" and get a list of questions and answers that the system attempt to suit to your tastes. I don't see the harm in having that, it exists in nearly every website. The only thing that differs is the quality of the implementation. It is a UX thing. I don't always come to this site to get a question answered.

Comment: @Arthur You should bring up that use case in your suggestion, since it was not clear why you were suggesting this. I'm in the same boat (I think) since I often come to my SE communities of choice to learn things from this archive of knowledge. Since features don't happen for free, though, I suggest you provide a use case for why SE users would benefit. The fact that other sites or Netflix have this feature is not, in itself, any reason why SE should do it.

Comment: I edited the question to improve it. Please edit the answer if you would like to. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: To be honest... After much though, the issue I'm running into is quite simple! Voting roughly measures: popularity * quality and I want something that reflects quality specifically, something roughly like voting / popularity.